# Svg doesnt show stroke

Tags: visual-studio, svg, stroke

I am working with many svg icons and now i have a problem on some of my svg icons.

The problem is that some of my svg icons doesnt show one ore more stroke lines.

[image: Image example]

my svg code here:

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
  <path style='fill:||FILL_COLOR||;stroke:||STROKE_COLOR||;stroke-width:||STROKE_WIDTH||;' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke' d='M19,17H5V7H19M19,5H5A2,2 0 0,0 3,7V17A2,2 0 0,0 5,19H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,17V7C21,5.89 20.1,5 19,5Z' />
</svg>
```

Thank you for all help

Comment: You're missing a `Z`. Change `d='M19,17H5V7H19M19` to `d='M19,17H5V7H19ZM19`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

Comment: But is there a way i can find this error in my other svg icons?

Comment: You should be able to do this in an SVG editor application. For example, in Affinity Designer, all you have to do is select the node tool (A), select everything (⌃A or ⌘A), and click the "Close Curve" button. (I'm assuming, of course, that your SVG doesn't contain any paths that are *intentionally* open.)